# Building a Map of Set using Java Streams

Tags: java, stream

I wrote a collector that would take a stream of `Map.Entry<Integer, MyObject>` which I want to make into `Map<Integer, Set<MyObject>>`

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
class MyObject {

}
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Set<MyObject>> collected = Stream.of(
       Map.entry(123, new MyObject()),
       Map.entry(123, new MyObject()),
       Map.entry(234, new MyObject()),
       Map.entry(345, new MyObject())
    )
    .collect(
      ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Set<MyObject>>::new,
      (map, entry) -> {
        map.computeIfAbsent(
          entry.getKey(), 
          k -> new HashSet<MyObject>()
        )
        .add(entry.getValue());
      },
      (map1, map2) -> {
        map2.forEach((map2Key, map2Object) -> {
          final Set<MyObject> objects = 
            map1.computeIfAbsent(map2Key, k -> new HashSet<MyObject>());
          objects.addAll(map2Object);
        });
      }
    );
    System.out.println(collected);
  }
}
```

I was wondering if there's a built in way of doing this, as it seems to be a common thing to do.

One way I can refactor this is to move the collector out to a different class like so:

```java
class EntryToMapCollector<K, V> implements Collector<Map.Entry<K, V>, Map<K, Collection<V>>, Map<K, Collection<V>>> {
    @Override
    public Supplier<Map<K, Collection<V>>> supplier() {
        return ConcurrentHashMap<K, Collection<V>>::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Map<K, Collection<V>>, Map.Entry<K, V>> accumulator() {
        return (map, entry) -> {
            map.computeIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), k -> new HashSet<V>())
                .add(entry.getValue());
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Map<K, Collection<V>>> combiner() {
        return (map1, map2) -> {
            final Map<K, Collection<V>> combined = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(map1);
            map2.forEach((map2Key, map2Observations) -> {
                combined.computeIfAbsent(map2Key, k -> new HashSet<V>())
                    .addAll(map2Observations);
            });
            return combined;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Map<K, Collection<V>>, Map<K, Collection<V>>> finisher() {
        return m -> m;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Set.of(Characteristics.CONCURRENT, Characteristics.UNORDERED);
    }
}
```

and replace the call with `.collect(new EntryToMapCollector<Integer, MyObject>());`

https://repl.it/@trajano/ForkedSpryRobot

Comment: Maybe thats a usecase for a multimap? https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: It would be if I used guava, I avoid guava because Google changes its mind on the API at its whim.

Comment: Sure, but i was referring to the concept of a multimap, guava's is a mere example. Apache Commons has it as well: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiMap.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [`.groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) and [`.toSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--)?

```
Map<Integer, Set<MyObject>> collected = Stream.of(...)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                   Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toSet())));
```

You possibly want [`.groupingByConcurrent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingByConcurrent-java.util.function.Function-) instead, though it is not exactly clear why.

Not a repl.it, but a JShell log:

```
U:\>jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 13
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> class MyObject { }
|  created class MyObject

jshell> Map<Integer, Set<MyObject>> result = Stream.of(
   ...>    Map.entry(123, new MyObject()),
   ...>    Map.entry(123, new MyObject()),
   ...>    Map.entry(234, new MyObject())
   ...> ).collect(
   ...>    Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(
   ...>       Map.Entry::getKey,
   ...>       Collectors.mapping(
   ...>          Map.Entry::getValue,
   ...>          Collectors.toSet()
   ...>       )
   ...>    )
   ...> );
result ==> {234=[MyObject@78c03f1f], 123=[MyObject@5ce81285, MyObject@52a86356]}

jshell>
```

Comment: what's `mapping`?

Comment: [`Collectors.mapping()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)

Comment: Do you mind posting a repl.it for your solution? I tried to put it in and I got `Main.java:17: error: incompatible types: inference variable D has incompatible equality constraints Collection<MyObject>,Set<T#2>`